# UIWebView Navigator userAgent property changing with iOS9 doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, user-agent

I have UIWebView where i need to change Navigator userAgent property.

For iOS version 10+ code below works perfectly:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    let script = "window.navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() " +
    "{ return '+keys +thatIs +neededTo +add'; });"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: script)
}
```

But with iOS9 this doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea?
In Info.plist I have set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user agent needs to be set in the UserDefaults.
You can use the following code to set it up.

```swift
func setUserAgent(as userAgentString: String) {
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": userAgentString])
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let userAgentString = "USER AGENT STRING HERE"
setUserAgent(as: userAgentString)
```

EDIT:

I see that you want to append some string to the current UserAgent.
For that you need to read the value for the current user agent, store it, add your custom string, then store the new user agent. Usage stays the same.

```swift
func setUserAgent(as value: String) {

    let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(width: 0, height: 0))
    let defaultUserAgentString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": defaultUserAgentString + " " + value])
    // remove the " " space if you don't need it
}
```

EDIT 2:

Yes, changing it will change it for all the web views across your app. To avoid this you can...

```swift
func setUserAgent(as value: String) {

    let webView = UIWebView()
    Constants.defaultUserAgentString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent") ?? ""

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": defaultUserAgentString + " " + value])
}

func resetUserAgent() {

    if let defaultString = Constants.defaultUserAgentString {
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": defaultString])
    }
}
```

`Constants` here is a struct/class that is used to store global constants, you may replace it with your own struct/class if you have one. Just add static variable `defaultUserAgentString` to keep track of the default user agent.
Use `resetUserAgent()` to switch back to the default user agent when you done. Maybe add it to `viewWillDisappear(`) on the `ViewController` handling the `WebView` that needs the modified user agent.

Comment: Thanks! It Works! Just out of curiosity do you know why my code worked with ios 10, but not with older versions. 
If I set in UserDefaults, then I'll need to remove it also? Otherwise it could influence other WebViews also?

Comment: I just tested it with iOS 9.2, it seems to work.
Yes, it will affect other WebViews as well. Refer to the EDIT 2 for a fix for that. Hope this answers your question.